# How many objects will create here?

Tags: java

```
String x = "a"+"b";
x = x+"c";
```

please, describe me how many object will create here with memory allocation.

Comment: This code won't compile since you're redeclaring `x`.

Comment: He is trying to learn about memory allocation not compiling of the program.. not sure why people are down voting.

Comment: No objects will be created. As this snippet will never be executed

Comment: Related: http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2015/10/common-misconception-how-many-objects.html?m=1

Comment: One option is to use `javap` to view the bytecode.

Answer (score 2):

```
String x = "a"+"b";
x = x+"c";
```

compiles to the following bytecode:

```
   0: ldc           #19                 // String ab
   2: astore_1
   3: new           #21                 // class java/lang/StringBuilder
   6: dup
   7: aload_1
   8: invokestatic  #23                 // Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;
  11: invokespecial #29                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":(Ljava/lang/String;)V
  14: ldc           #32                 // String c
  16: invokevirtual #34                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
  19: invokevirtual #38                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
  22: astore_1
```

As you can see, the constant expression `"a"+"b"` is converted to `"ab"` by the compiler, and `x = x+"c"` compiles to (Java 9.0.1):

```
x = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(x)).append("c").toString();
```

You therefore get these objects:

- `"ab"` in string pool
- `"c"` in string pool
- `StringBuilder`
- `char[]` inside `StringBuilder`
- `String` returned by `StringBuilder`
- `byte[]` inside *each* `String`

So if you don't count string literals in the string pool:

(`StringBuilder` + `char[]`) + (`String` + `byte[]`) = 4 objects

*Note: `StringBuilder` only allocates 1 `char[]` since it is preallocated with 16 extra characters, enough for the 1 extra character that is appended, i.e. no buffer re-allocation.*

If you do count string literals in the string pool (and you should), you get additional:

2 * (`String` + `byte[]`) = 4 objects

For a total of **8 objects**.

The above doesn't account for optimizations performed by JIT.

Comment: Only this answer is actual answer to this question..

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know how java manages Strings in memory.

Whenever you create a string object using string literal, that object is stored in the string constant pool and whenever you create a string object using new keyword, such object is stored in the heap memory.

For example, when you create string objects like below, they will be stored in the String Constant Pool.

```
String s1 = "abc"; 

String s2 = "xyz";

String s3 = "123";

String s4 = "A";
```

And when you create string objects using new keyword like below, they will be stored in the heap memory.

```
String s5 = new String("abc");

char[] c = {'J', 'A', 'V', 'A'};

String s6 = new String(c);

String s7 = new String(new StringBuffer());
```

This is how String Constant Pool looks like in the memory.
[image]

One more interesting thing about String Constant Pool is that, pool space is allocated to an object depending upon it’s content. There will be no two objects in the pool having the same content.

This is what happens when you create string objects using string literal,

“When you create a string object using string literal, JVM first checks the content of to be created object. If there exist an object in the pool with the same content, then it returns the reference of that object. It doesn’t create new object. If the content is different from the existing objects then only it creates new object.”

But, when you create string objects using new keyword, a new object is created whether the content is same or not

Hope it puts you on the correct path.

Source : https://javaconceptoftheday.com/how-the-strings-are-stored-in-the-memory/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, as that site may change and then will invalidate this post. Would you mind to at least put a summary into your answer of what the article tries ro claim. Citations will do

Comment: @Lino Done I have undated my answer.

Comment: This doesn't help answer the question. It doesn't cover what happens with `"a"+"b"` (2 strings... no, 1 string, so 2 objects) or how many objects are created by `x+"c"` (6 objects).

Answer (score -3):

There will be one String object generated called `x`. 
Value of "x" at the first line ist: "ab".

At the second line you add the value of `x` to the object `x` plus you add "c".
So the new value will be "abc".

So to answer your question, only ONE object will be generated with this code.

Comment: Actually, those 2 lines of code creates [8 objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51532157/5221149).

Comment: Please delete this answer since it simply is factually wrong.